# fixing ssl_error_rx_record_too_long from cpanel

Tags: ssl, cpanel

I've seen this question many times but all answers can't help me because I only rented server space and am not able to administer it.

I did the following:

I've bought a domain and ssl certificate from PositiveSSL
I've bought hosting space with a dedicated IP
I' only have cpanel with access to SSL/TLS Manager
I've created the CSR and everything and added and verified the certificate and got it.
I've then added it through SSL/TLS Manager and it should be working fine.

Now the problem:
When I try to open the website using `https://www.mysite.com` I get this error:

```
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to www.mysite.com.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

What can I do in this case? My hosting provider has almost no idea about SSL and won't help me anymore :( so I only have access to cpanel and SSL/TLS Manager.

I've tried to reinstall it many times but the error stays.

Comment: Can you post a packet capture?  Alternately, would you mind posting a link to the actual site?

Answer (score 2):

SSl certificate will require a reserved IP on cpanel environment. As you have only access to your cpanel and not WHM, this mean you are on shared hosting environment. Which means your websites use the server shared/main IP.
solution: Ask your web-hoster to provide you with a dedicated IP for your domain with ssl

Technicaly, there is another solution, but they will say NO : Provide your web-hoster with the crt and ask him to install it trough WHM, they will have to reset the ssl vhost to nobody. This is where they will say NO!
when they will paste  the crt content in the proper field to install your ssl, they wil click "fetch"  this will load you private key and CA (if any) in the fields bellow. The most important are 2 fields just underneath the crt field: IP and user. In shared hosting CPANEL, each domain/website scripts will run under its correspondent user. Cpanel will not allow a user to run an ssl vhost on shared IP (cpanel is already using it for its own self signed certificate). The web_hosters need to know which user / is using how much ressources.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The error can be due to multiple reasons

a) The Port number for https connection is not open

b) The private key does not match with the public key